# where to store the php connection file?

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I am using ipage shared hosting now. My prior hosting allowed me to store php connection outside the root. However, I don't see this the case for ipage now. How do you guys store this information?

```
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$host="AcctUsername.ipagemysql.com";
$database="your_database"

$conn = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
```

Comment: *"where to store the php connection file?"* - that is entirely up to you. Want a safe place? Store it outside public, just like they said.

Comment: Can't you set the root of your webhosting to another path?

Answer (score 0):

Just store it anywhere. It's a php file and that means no one can really see your password. If you can store it somewhere outside of the public html folder that would be better but not really that important.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere outside the public html / web root would be fine.

Please don't call it .inc as you see people sometimes do. Apache will just show the contents of the file if it accidentally ends up in the root.

Final tip: if you use git or some other source control, do not put the file inside your repository (especially public repo's) as this might expose the credentials.